# Error installing eOS 7.1 on Mac Mini 2011

Tags: system-installation

I tried to install eOS 7.1 on a Mac Mini 2011 with a fresh SSD from USB stick.

Select "erase and install", select disk (SSD), no encryption, start.
After 20% an error message comes:
"the device may not restart properly".

In detail, there are at the end some error messages about partitions. I don't understand this correctly.

How can I recognize and resolve the error?